# Ember Iterating through a promise/ store.findAll return value

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

In my router I have code `let users= this.store.findAll('user')`

And my model user.js will be `name: DS.attr('string'), userName: DS.attr('string'), company: DS.attr('string')`

In my mirage fixture I have User object defined as  `[{'name':'smith','userName':'smith123'},{'name':'james','userName':'james222'}`

And in my router when I do  `let users= this.store.findAll('user')` I want to iterate through `users` and add `company` manually for each user. But I am unable to find the way to access the user objects in router js file.

And same object I can iterate in `.hbs` file. But unable to find the way to iterate it in router `js` file. Can you please let me know the way to do this.

Comment: Did you read [ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/)? They cover all basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findAll` method (and `findRecord` too) returns a [promise](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/RSVP.Promise), not iterable object. You can iterate through users after promise will be resolved. To do this, you should use `then` method:

```
this.store.findAll('user')
  .then(users => {
    /*Iterate here*/
  })
  .catch(error => {
    /*Do something to inform user about network/server/request error here*/
  });
```